# MySQL SUM across 4 tables based on userID

Tags: mysql

I am new to this and I need help - I need to do a SUM on 4 different tables based on a ID.

example:
table1.points
table2.points
table3.points
table4.points
user.userID

as points

I need to calculate all the points in the four tables based on the userID

any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: I need to be more specific  - I need to look at all four tables for the userID and sum up the points in the tables...

Comment: I have tried this and it does give me a sum... but its WAY OFF from the actual points

Answer (score 0):

yon can use this code for sum all points

```
select 
sum(a.point)
from
(select sum(point) as point from table1 where userid =1
 union all
 select sum(point) as point from table2 where userid =1
union all
  select sum(point) as point from table3 where userid =1
) a
```

Comment: SELECT
SUM(a.points)
FROM
(select sum(points) as point from show1 where show1.dogID = dogs.dogID
 union all
 select sum(points) as point from show2 where show2.dogID = dogs.dogID
union all
  select sum(points) as point from show3 where show3.dogID = dogs.dogID
union all
 select sum(points) as points from show4 where show4.dogID = dogs.dogID
) a 
FROM dogs     Didn't work

Comment: Error executing query.
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT
SUM(a.points)
FROM
(select sum(points) as point from show1 where show1'

Comment: can you use show1.dogID = dogs.dogID (show1.dogID = 1 or static value for test, you have not value in this query

Comment: SELECT SUM(a.points) FROM (select sum(points) as point from show1 where show1.dogID = 2 union all select sum(points) as point from show2 where show2.dogID = 2 union all select sum(points) as point from show3 where show3.dogID = 2 union all select sum(points) as points from show4 where show4.dogID = 2 ) a 

something like this

Comment: Still get same error:   SELECT SUM(a.points) FROM (select sum(points) as point from show1 where show1.dogID = 1604 union all select sum(points) as point from show2 where show2.dogID = 1604 union all select sum(points) as point from show3 where show3.dogID = 1604 union all select sum(points) as points from show4 where show4.dogID = 1604 ) a 

FROM dogs

Comment: SELECT SUM(dogs.total_point) FROM (select sum(points) as total_point from show1 where show1.dogID = 1604 union all select sum(points) as total_point from show2 where show2.dogID = 1604 union all select sum(points) as total_point from show3 where show3.dogID = 1604 union all select sum(points) as total_point from show4 where show4.dogID = 1604 ) dogs

use this

Comment: use this above query

Comment: Error executing query.
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT SUM(dogs.total_point) FROM (select sum(points) as total_point from show1 ' at line 19

SELECT

Comment: I can't post the query...   The column name in the show tables is "dog" and the column in the dog table is dogID

Comment: SELECT SUM(dogs.total_point) FROM (select sum(points) as total_point from show1 where show1.dog = 1604 union all select sum(points) as total_point from show2 where show2.dog = 1604 union all select sum(points) as total_point from show3 where show3.dog = 1604 union all select sum(points) as total_point from show4 where show4.dog = 1604 ) 
FROM dogs

Comment: please check show1 and other table name and table column name same and points column also, otherwise query must work, i have checked already

Comment: thank you, will keep on trying... I appreciate your help... will post final results when I get it working...

Comment: ok but just check table name and column name then i am sure it will work

Comment: I just checked each column and table - all are the same... dogs.dogID and showX.dog.... I am confused as to why... will keep digging.

Comment: can you give four table name and all column field ? or give me screenshot all table?

Comment: last thing that your four table name must be show1,show2,show3 and show4 and in every table dog will be filed name which condition field and points filed your point calculation , otherwise it will not work

Comment: How do I send a screen shot to you?

Comment: The show tables are named... show1, show2, show3, show4 with a column named "points"(int)  and a column named "dog"(int) the dogs table has the "dogID" as the unique id...  [link]http://cbrdogs.com/images/dogtable.png  [link]http://cbrdogs.com/images/show_tables.png all show tables are identicle

Comment: select sum(points) as total_point from show1 where show1.dog = 1604

use this for show1 table and same other , if it will work then inform me but show2 table need dog column ,same other